# How to find the kth term of following function F mentioned in description in Assembly

Tags: assembly

```
The function F is defined as F(1) = F(2) = F(3) = 1 and for n  3,
F(n + 1) = F(n)  (F(n - 1) + F(n - 2))
i.e., the (n + 1)th value is given by the product of the nth value and
the sum of the (n - 1)th and (n - 2)th values.

Write an assembly program for computing the kth value F(k),
where k is an integer bigger than 3 read from a memory location
M, and storing F(k) at memory location M.
```

This is my code for the above question. But i am facing problem relating output. For 1,2,3,4,5,6 its is showing right output 
But for 7 Output must be 72 
for 8 it should be 1152 
and for 9 it should be 96768.
 [Click here to see the image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM9OF.jpg)

```
DATA SEGMENT
NUM1 DB 1
NUM2 DB 1
NUM3 DB 1
k DB ?
RESULT DB ?
MSG1 DB 10,13,"ENTER VALUE OF k: $"
MSG3 DB 10,13,"RESULT F(k) = $"
ENDS
CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME DS:DATA, CS:CODE
START:
MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX
LEA DX,MSG1
MOV AH,9
INT 21H
MOV AH,1
INT 21H
SUB AL,30H
MOV k,AL        ; Input value of k stored in k
CMP AL,4
JL SETONE       ; if input is less than 4 than set result to 1
MOV BL,3    ; Counter BL = 4
LOOPSTART:
MOV CL,NUM2     ; 2nd Last Value stored in CX
MOV DL,NUM1     ; 3rd Last Value stored in DX
ADD CL,DL       ; CX= CX+DX
MOV AL,NUM3     ; Last Value stored in AX
MUL CL          ; AX= AX*CX
;ADD AX,30H
AAM
MOV DH,NUM2
MOV NUM1,DH
MOV DH,NUM3
MOV NUM2,DH
MOV NUM3,AL
INC BL
MOV CL,k
CMP BL,CL
JNE LOOPSTART
JMP SHOWRESULT
SETONE:         ; jump here if k is less than 4
MOV AL,1        ; set result = 1
MOV RESULT,AL

SHOWRESULT:
ADD AH,30H
ADD AL,30H
MOV BX,AX
LEA DX,MSG3
MOV AH,9
INT 21H
MOV AH,2
MOV DL,BH
INT 21H
MOV AH,2
MOV DL,BL
INT 21H
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
ENDS
END START
```

Additional : Algorithm to solve this problem is also available in answer no 1.
My assignment says to store result in memory. But i wants to display result for learning prospective.

Comment: Unless there's some stupid requirement to make it recursive, you just need 4 registers to keep track of that last 3 values in the sequence.  One more than a plain Fibonacci sequence.  If you're using x86, see [X86 Fibonacci program](//stackoverflow.com/a/36235362) for an example of that.  Just add another `mov` and an `imul eax, edx` or something in there somewhere.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for help its done, therez no such requirement to make it recursive.

Comment: [edit] your attempt into the question, along with details on what exactly *does* happen when you run it.  [mcve].  Code is unreadable in a comment.  (But from the `sub al, 30h` I saw without any `div` instruction, you're probably using something that only works for single-digit numbers.  That's obviously not going to work.  See the multi-digit number section in the FAQ in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  Oh, with AAM maybe it works for 2-digit numbers.

Comment: @PeterCordes : see my answer below for code and also attached image of output. 
Check that answer and help me finding the problem with output

Comment: If you need it to work for an output of 96768, that doesn't fit in 16 bits so you'll need to either use 32-bit registers or use the 32-bit DX:AX result of `mul cx`  (not `mul cl`, which doesn't do what your comment says.)  Your `R` "variable" never needs to exist in memory, just registers.  Or actually the assignment says to store it in memory; that's easier than printing it.

Comment: @PeterCordes : Okay but it should work for 72, 1152 which is also not working

Comment: Yes assignment actually says to store in memory

Comment: Your `aam` is in the wrong place, inside the loop.  Work with binary integers inside the loop, not unpacked BCD.  Also, you're making things hard for yourself by doing ASCII string I/O instead of just loading a 16-bit integer before the loop and storing a 32-bit integer from DX:AX after the loop.  (Inside the loop you might just only look at the low 16 bits of the `mul` result for your t3,t2, and t1, to keep it simple, but allow extra range for that final output.)

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm: It was easier than i thought. a simple algorithm i developed:
let `t1=1,t2=1,t3=1` for storing last three values, and `R` for storing result.

```
    -- Input n
IF(n<=3){
    R=1
} else  {
    limit=n;
    counter=4;
    While(counter!=n){
        R=t3*(t2+t1);
        t1=t2;
        t2=t3;
        t3=R;
        counter++;
    }
}
Print R;
```